# Joining two lists into tuples in python

Tags: python, list

I want to use the join function in python (not any other function) to merge two lists into nested lists, assuming the lists are of equal length, for example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I want it to produce a new list like this:

```
[[1,"a"], [2,"b"], [3,"c"]]
```

Comment: What "join function" are you talking about? join is not a builtin function in python2. Do you mean some module's join function? Some object's join method?

Comment: Haven't tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to zip two lists of lists in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474717/how-to-zip-two-lists-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Title says tuple and example expects list. How's that?

Comment: @Brad No, that problem is significantly different (more complicated).

Comment: possible duplicate of [python list of lists transpose without zip(\*m) thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/python-list-of-lists-transpose-without-zipm-thing)

Comment: I didn't mean a tuple, and I want to do it using the join function in the string module

Comment: If you want to join a list of integers and a list of strings into a list of lists of integers and strings, `string.join` isn't going to help you much.  Unsurprisingly, it's for joining strings together to make a new string.

Comment: So if the two lists were of strings, say each number was a string, how would you use string.join to interleave them like ["1","a"], ["2","b"] etc?

Comment: You still wouldn't.  `string.join` accepts strings, and outputs a *string*.  [You could use a string as an intermediate object, I guess, but it'd be pointless.]

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you understand what `str.join` is for.

[`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is a string method that takes an iterable (usually a list) of strings and returns a new string object that is a concatenation of those strings separated by the string that the method was invoked on.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> strs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ''.join(strs)
'abc'
>>> '--'.join(strs)
'a--b--c'
>>>
```

This means that you would not use `str.join` for what you are trying to do.  Instead, you can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
>>>
```

Note however that, if you are on Python 2.x, you may want to use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of `zip`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> [list(x) for x in izip(list1, list2)]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
>>>
```

Like the Python 3.x `zip`, `itertools.izip` will return an iterator (instead of a list like the Python 2.x `zip`).  This makes it more efficient, especially when dealing with larger lists.

Comment: @user3208158 - [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is a string method that returns a string, not a list.  So no, you would not use it for this task.

Answer (score 1):

```
list(map(list, zip(list1, list2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! The join function you are looking for in this context, my friend, is the following:

```
def join(l1, l2):
    return [list(x) for x in zip(l1, l2)]

print join(list1, list2)
```

:-)