# How do I make a list concatenating the corresponding elements of two lists of strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, loops, concatenation

I want to make a new list concatenating the corresponding elements of lists of equal-sized strings. For instance, for

```py
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = ["d","e","f"]
```

,
the output should be

```py
["ad", "be", "cf"]
```

Comment: You are getting some quality answers for your question, but for future reference, do remember to include some information about what *you* already tried to solve a given problem in your questions. Related/bordering on duplicate: [Joining two lists into tuples in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21196165/1199226)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> one = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> two = ["d", "e", "f"]
>>> map(add, one, two)
['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

Comment: you can use `str.__add__` instead of importing add operator

Comment: @Elisha Indeed, but for bigger lists it can be a little slower.

Comment: doesn't `add` operator just uses `str.__add__` ?

Comment: @Elisha Internally yes, but explicit calls to these special methods is always slower than implicit calls.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your chars should be in single/double quotes:

```
listone = ['a', 'b', 'c']
listtwo = ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

Then you can do:

```
listthree = [i+j for i,j in zip(listone,listtwo)]

>>> print listthree
['ad', 'be', 'cf']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension and the `zip()` method-

```
print [m + n for m, n in zip(listone, listtwo)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `join` instead of `+`

```
print [''.join(x) for x in zip(listone, listtwo)]
```